# Overlaying a map image atop a Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to overlay a historical map atop the original in Leaflet. The map is of an entire country. The markers should still appear over the map, as well as popups when clicking on those markers. I was wondering if/how this would be possible, and if the map would stay 'fixed' on that country regardless of resizing/scaling.

Comment: Have you had a look at `L.ImageOverlay`?

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that in the documentation, but it looks perfect. Thanks for the heads-up!